# Parking brake alarm will not stop

Tags: mercedes-benz, alarm, parking-brake

My husband's 1999 ML430 is on its last legs, and we're trying to sink as little money into it as possible and just get him a better car soon. However, this week, the parking brake alarm won't stop dinging, even when the parking brake is clearly released. Is there an easy DIY method to get it to recalibrate, or maybe even disable it? (Assuming that's legal! If not please let me know!).

Comment: Glad I could help :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check to ensure you have enough fluid in the brake master cylinder. A lot of vehicles have the sensor which detects the level of the fluid in on the same circuit as the parking brake. If you find this low, you may want to check the condition of your brake pads. If the brake pads are thin, there is more fluid residing in your calipers which would in turn give you less fluid in your reservoir.